# How deep does the GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren() , Go?

Tags: unity, gameobject, game-component

So I have a `GameObject` which my scene will be it's children.
I wanted to get the `BoxCollider` of all the objects and their sub-objects and their sub-objects's sub-objects and ... .
So can I do that with just the `GetComponentsInChildren()`, or should I navigate through them all and find them one by one?

Comment: You provide a link to *official documetation* that clearly  states you can, why did you think you could not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you link covers the answer to this, quite clearly. `GetComponentsInChildren` will return components from *all* sub children.

---

This is the API reference you link, emphasis mine:

> **Description**
>   Returns all components of `Type type` in the `GameObject` or ***any of its children***.
>   The search for components is carried out ***recursively*** on child objects, ***so it includes children of children, and so on***.
>    <sub>- [Unity API: GameObject. GetComponentsInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html)</sub>

Comment: Sorry, I tested it and it wasn't clear if it worked properly so I asked to make sure of that, and thank you